# Envio de mails no funciona

Tags: php, html, mail

Tengo un sistema de tickets interno de la empresa el cual funciona bien, pero no envia los correos cuando crean el ticket y cuando el mismo se cierra.
El mismo debe notificar la apertura del ticket, al que lo creo y a soporte, lo mismo al cierre.

Esto es parte final de la creacion del ticket, donde debe hacer el envio, es lo mismo en el perfil admin, y en el perfil del usuario.

```
    ob_start();
      include(APPPATH.'libraries/DetailsTicket.php');
    $body = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $this->load->library('email');
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->to('test@gmail.com');
    $this->email->from('test@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Detalle ticket');
    $this->email->message($body);
    $this->email->send();
  }
}
```

Sumo donde tengo todo el código para que vean la configuración de mail:

https://github.com/DRanieri/SistemaTickets/tree/main/system/libraries

Comment: Sale algo en los logs de PHP? Qué configuración de servidor SMTP usas?

Comment: https://github.com/DRanieri/SistemaTickets/tree/main/system/libraries

Aca tengo todo el codigo.

Comment: Las preguntas son autocontenidas. Pon el código relevante en la pregunta, por favor. Cuando cambies ese proyecto, la pregunta puede terminar siendo inútil para otros en el futuro con el mismo problema

Comment: Supongo que usas PHPMailer. Entonces escribe tu código con captura de errores, [como se muestra en este ejemplo](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example, observa sobre todo la parte del `try ... catch`, así sabrás qué es lo que no está funcionando.

Comment: Buenos dias! no uso phpmailer, uso este archivo https://github.com/DRanieri/SistemaTickets/blob/main/system/libraries/Email.php

Comment: Especifica tu versión de Codeigniter. Intenta hacer debug del código poniendo algo así: `if( !$this->email->send(FALSE) ) { $this->email->print_debugger();  }`